# Show both are equivalent.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$\exists xP(x)\implies P(y)$ is equivalent to     $\forall x(P(x)\implies P(y))$

What can I show in this question to prove that they are equivalent.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you express $\implies$ using $\lor$ and $\neg$?

Comment: yes we can use it

Comment: I assumed so. How would you do it with these formulas, what do you get?

Comment: thou shalt use it then :) If it helps you may also consider negations of the given statements and prove them equivalent.

Comment: In any case you're also going to have to use the rules for moving a quantifier past a negation -- or, what comes to the same thing, moving a negation past a quantifier.. interchanging their positions.

Comment: i also thought of changing the implication by negation sign and getting expression in terms of negation and conjunction but stuck there and not able to proceed further.

Comment: Why not? Write down what you get. It's easier to use negation and disjunction.

Comment: i first converted imply to negation so got there exist x ~P(x) \/ P(y) then

Comment: then how shoud I proceed further?

Comment: @BrianO I am confused myself :) Are we supposed to assume a universal quantifier for $y$? Otherwise we may fix $y$ with $P(y)$ false, and if $P(x)$ is false for some but not all $x$ then it looks like the formulas are not equivalent ... the meta-conclusion being that an universal quantifier is assumed (and I should clarify it to myself before trying to explain) ? Anyway, please do not bother, unless the OP provides more details as to what they tried so far.

Comment: No @Shubham , the statement is $\color{red}{\big(}\exists x\;P(x)\color{red}{\big)}\;\to\; P(y)$.  You have to negate the entire antecedent, not just its predicate.

Comment: @Miko $y$ is an unbound entity.  Treat it as a constant.

Comment: Shubham if you wish that someone who left a comment receive a notification that you left a comment for them, you need to write their user name preceded by the "at" sign, like @BrianO

Comment: Consider cases (and once you get it rewrite everything formally). If $P(y)$ is true, then both formulas are true. Now assume $P(y)$ is false. Then the second formula would be true only of all $P(x)$ were false (and in that case the first formula would be true also, being $F\to F$). The second formula would be (evaluate to) false if some $P(x)$ were true (why?), and in this case the first formula would be false too.

Comment: OK but if you convert $\exists x P(x) \to P(y)$ to use $\lor$ and $\neg$, what do you get?

Comment: I suppose the answer to that is, You get someone else to solve the problem ;)

Comment: @Mirko Thanks Sir.Since I am new to math.stackexchange so it will take a couple of days to know all these things.Thanks for all your support.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks Sir,your help solved my work,your last to last comment gave me the answer.

Comment: Oh good. I was trying to get you to confront $\neg\exists x$; you have to first transform it into $\forall x\neg$. Then you can move $\forall x$ to the outer scope, which is safe because $x$ is not free in $P(y)$ (and then you can convert the inner formula back to $\!\implies\!\!$).

Comment: See my formal proof (DC Proof format) at http://www.dcproof.com/MSE2015-12-01.htm

Answer (score 2):

It is [intuitionistically provable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic), although proof by cases or De Morgan laws don't show this. A deductive proof:

> ($\to$) Suppose that $\exists x P(x)\to Q$. Suppose $P(x)$. Then $\exists x P(x)$, so by MP $Q$ is true. Thus $P(x)\to Q$, and this is true for arbitrary $x$, $\forall x(P(x)\to Q)$.
>
> ($\leftarrow$) Suppose that $\forall x(P(x)\to Q)$. Take some $x$, so $P(x)\to Q$. Since $Q$ does not depend on $x$, deduce $\exists x P(x)\to Q$.
>
> Thus $(\exists x P(x)\to Q)\iff \forall x(P(x)\to Q)$.

This theorem is sometimes taken as the "definition" of $\exists x P(x)$ in intuitionistic logic. In classical logic it is sufficient to take $Q=\bot$ so that it simplifies to $\lnot\exists x P(x)\iff \forall x\lnot P(x)$, the De Morgan law for quantifiers, and another contraposition yields an actual definitional theorem, $\exists x P(x)\iff \lnot\forall x\lnot P(x)$. In intuitionistic logic these two are not equivalent, but the version with $Q$ is a useful substitute.

Comment: I suggest, begin the second part: Suppose that $\forall x (P(x) \to Q)$. Suppose $\exists x (P(x))$...

Comment: @DanChristensen The intent with the wording is that I am explicitly invoking the rule of existential generalization: if $P(x)\to Q$ and $x$ is not free in $Q$, then $(\exists x P(x))\to Q$. This is only a thinly veiled English language version of a formal proof, so I wanted to limit the "moves" to those which correspond closely to axioms.

Comment: Here is my formal proof (in DC Proof format): http://www.dcproof.com/MSE2015-12-01.htm See lines 7 and 8 in particular.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly a matter of using DeMorgan rule for quantifiers:

$$\exists x P(x)\rightarrow P(y)$$
$$\neg \exists x P(x)\lor P(y)$$
$$\forall x \neg P(x)\lor P(y)$$
$$\forall x (\neg P(x)\lor P(y))$$
$$\forall x (P(x)\rightarrow P(y))$$

The step between the third and fourth is because $P(y)$ doesn't depend on $x$.